# How can I secure static content in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an HTML user guide for my application. But I don't want those who are not logged in to be able to access it.  I am using Devise authentication and CanCan authorization.

Comment: All good answers, but I have not gotten any of them to work. I am surprised by the difficulty of this.

Another problem is that even if I get these pages to be served up, Rails is seeing static urls like 'src="help.htm" in the source files and prepending them with a slash. So instead of being a relative link, they are being served up as absolute links. How can I fix that?

Comment: check this short railscast, and see if it helps you to create something similar to your environment http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store it outside the public folder and serve it through a simple controller that just performs the authentication check. Doing this with x-sendfile ( https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ ) should minimize the additional server load. Here's a rough guide: http://elivz.com/blog/single/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: My problem with this is that we are served up in production using Nginx via EngineYard.

Comment: no problem with nginx either - it implemented nearly the same feature with x-accel-redirect - see http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile

Comment: Is there a guide to this approach. I'd be interested to see how the controller would look like etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familier with the authentication method that you are using, but once you authenticate a user you can save logged_in flag in your session

```
session[:user]='logged_in'
```

than you can create a helper

```
def logged_in?
  session[:user] =='logged_in'
end
```

Now you will be abe to use this helper in you views

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  your html
<% end %>
```

Now this is very basic, if you need something more specific let us know

--So I just noticed that you want to make sure that only logged in users will be able to see the whole page.

then you should use you authenticate function as a before filter in you controller

```
before_filter :authenticate
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) plugin.

This is a fairly simple controller designed to serve static content.  Authenticate by extending HighVoltage::PagesController and handling authentication like you would with any other controller (minimal example available on the linked page).

Comment: Thanks ropperman. I tried it, but it doesn't appear that you can turn off layouts.